Old bath exhaust fan
Anyone seen this exhaust fan? How easy it is to replace this with a new exhaust fan.
It is very ugly
I will provide more details like the size

More details are needed about the fan and your abilities, and available tools.  Otherwise it is impossible to tell how "easy" it is.   What may be easy to some of us on here may be impossible to someone else.

not easy at all, you have light+fan

There are three main issues with replacing an exhaust fan:

Size - This is actually the size of the hole in the ceiling, which is generally slightly smaller than the visible portion of the fan. Take the existing fan down ("how" will depend on the model, but I'd look for screws underneath the light cover first) and measure the existing hole. Installing a larger fan is usually not a problem but installing a smaller one may require drywall work.

Wiring - Most of the time (at least in the US) there will be either a 2-wire (plus ground) or 3-wire (plus ground) connection - i.e., either switched hot for everything + neutral, or switched hot for fan + switched hot for light + neutral. Before disconnecting any wires (a) make sure that power is off (circuit breaker, not wall switch) and (b) take pictures. Do not disconnect miscellaneous wire nuts and other connections - if there are multiple cables, "extra" wires, etc. they are all there for a reason which will almost certainly apply in exactly the same way with a new fan.

Ductwork - Typically a flexible duct, but sometimes rigid, going to either a hole in the roof or out a side wall. Measure it as a new fan might need a larger or smaller duct. You can adapt from one size to another, but sometimes that can cause performance issues.



How easy it is to replace this with a new exhaust fan.

@DIY75 And how easy will depend on: can you match the size, are the wires suitable for a new fan, is the ductwork the same size or close enough that it can be adapted.

Bottom line here there is no way anyone can answer the OP that the job will be easy or not.
